# How to force Hibernate use AND in update query?

Tags: java, hibernate, mariadb

I am trying to update a raw by composite primary key by using hibernate.

Hibernate uses the next style for such updates:

```
update mytable set mycolumn=321 where (left_pk, right_pk) = (123, 456);
```

Is it possible to force hibernate to use the next style?:

```
update mytable set mycolumn=321 where left_pk = 123 and right_pk = 456;
```

Both queries work but with a huge difference (at least in MariaDB).
If we use `repeatable read` transaction then the first query locks the whole table for updates and the second query locks only the single row for updates.

I would prefer to lock only a single row, so I need to use the second query.

Comment: Yeah, "row constructors" are _not_ well optimized.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for `NamedQueries` approach in Hibernate,
For example:

```
 //Create Query 
 @NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "   YOUR QUERY NAME", 
        query = "from DeptEmployee where department = :department and emp = :emp") })


// set multiple parameters
 query.setParameter("department",department)
     .setParameter("emp", emp)
```

Try giving this a shot.